# Filestream Create issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, io

I have code running on sharepoint server, which is giving me headaches .
Problem is with Filstream.create which throws this exception

exception at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at

The code block where exception is thrown is

```
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(TargetPath, FileMode.Create))
                {


                    BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(readStream);
                    BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                    int allBytes = (int)readStream.Length;
                    bWriter.Write(bReader.ReadBytes(allBytes));
                    //bReader.Close();
                    //bWriter.Close();
                }
```

Does anyone have an idea , about how to go about this?

Comment: Does the TargetPath exist?  Is there already a file there with the same name?  What is the exception message?

Comment: Exception message would be helpfull, since at this point it could be one of a few things causing the IOException (File Exists, File in use, insufficient permissions)

Comment: that message that i have posted is all i get as exception message.It comes very inconsistently on server.whether file exists or not.

Comment: The error message is "Access to the path is denied".